# dropdwnlist autopostback not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

dropdwnlist autopostback not working 
my code as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged" >
   <%--  <asp:ListItem Selected="True">--Select--</asp:ListItem>--%>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Codebehind is:

```
protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlDistrict.Enabled = true;
    ddlTaluka.Enabled = true;
    DataTable dtObj = new DataTable();
    using (var client = ServiceClient<IPallaviAddressManager>.Create("PallaviAddressManager"))
    {
        dtObj = client.Instance.GetAllStates();
    }
    var result = (from dt in dtObj.AsEnumerable()
                      where dt.Field<Int64>("StateID") == Convert.ToInt64(ddlState.SelectedValue)
                      select dt);
    dtObj = result.CopyToDataTable();
    ddlDistrict.DataSource = dtObj;
    ddlState.DataTextField = "Description";
    ddlState.DataValueField = "DistrictID";
}
```

Can you help?

Comment: What part of it is not working.  Is that function never getting called?

Comment: And why are you resetting the DataTextField, and DataValueField on your ddlState at the end of that event?

Comment: Try adding `ddlDistrict.DataBind();` to your code, this might cause the new items to show in that drop down.

Comment: Is the AutoPostBack just not working or is the code failing? You question is not clear.

Comment: Can you please show us your page_load code?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to `runat="server"` and `autopostback="true"`

Comment: I think you meant `true` not `tru`.

Comment: Not relevant anymore, OP didn't format the code properly that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ddlDistrict.DataBind(); at the end of the code, as Shadow Wizard suggested

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the event hasn't been hooked up properly.

Try selecting the DropDownList control in the designer, going to the properties tab and double clicking in the space to the right of the SelectedIndexChanged event, if it creates a new stub in the code-behind then the original event wasn't hooked properly.